$abab$ is a $4$ digit number(if $a=1$ and $b=2$ and the $4$ digit number will be $1212$). if $abab$ has the maximum amount of factors, $abab_{min}=?$
Problem: $abab$ is a $4$ digit number(if $a=1$ and $b=2$ and the $4$ digit number will be $1212$). if $abab$ has the maximum amount of factors, $abab_{min}=?$
My approach:
$abab=1000a+100b+10a+b=1001a+101b=101(10a+b)$
So, I have to find out a $2$ digit minimum number with maximum factors. I tried brute forcing and I got $60$. So, $abab=6060$.(I wrote python code to find that out. There could be any problem in my code. If I made a mistake, I am sorry for it.)
Conclusion: How can I find the minimum $2$ digit number with maximum amount of factors without brute forcing? This is a math competition practice question so this has to be done in a time limit.

What is the $min$ subscript?  You are asking for the maximum number of factors.  Do you know the formula for the number of divisors of a number based on its prime factorization?  It is in Wikipedia.

I want $abab$ to be minimum.

There are many $4$ digit numbers with the same number of factors. So, I am wanting minimum $abab$.

But, the formula will only work for prime factorization. I can't use that. That's why I am asking for help.

How do you define the  amount of factors?

like $8$ has $4$ factors. $1,2,4,8$.

Why can't you use prime factorization?  The point is that any number of the shape $pqr$ where they are all prime has $8$ factors.  Any number with the shape $p^2q$ has only six factors, while $p^3q$ has $8$.  That doesn't leave many to try once you know that $2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \lt 100$

My answer agrees with the answer of Especially Lime.  Further, my analysis is very similar to his.  I simply express my analysis differently.
Any positive integer $~c~$ whose prime factorization is
$ ~\left[ ~\prod_{i = 1}^k (p_i)^{x_i} ~\right] ~$
will have $~\left[ ~\displaystyle \prod_{i = 1}^k (x_i + 1) ~\right] ~$ factors.
Further, any positive integer $~c~$ that has form abab will be divisible by the prime number $~101.~$  Note further that $~101^2 > 10000.~$
So, in searching for the appropriate positive integer $~c,~$ you are locked in to having the prime factorization of $~c~$ include the factor $~(101)^1.~$
Therefore, you are looking for a positive integer $~d~$ such that $~101 \times d~$ has form abab.
Therefore, the problem reduces to finding the appropriate positive integer $~d~$ such that

$10 \leq d \leq 99.$

Of all the integers in $~[10,99]~$ with the maximum number of factors, $~d~$ is the smallest.


Since $~2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 > 99,~$ the integer $~d~$ can have no more than $~3~$ distinct prime factors.  Therefore, you can immediately conclude that $~d~$ must

Have form $~2^r \times 3^s \times 5^t,$

Where $~r,s,t \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},$

And $~r \geq s \geq t.$


The third bullet point above can be justified as follows:
Suppose that $~r \geq s \geq t.~$
Then, of the $~6~$ elements
$$(2^r \times 3^s \times 5^t), ~(2^r \times 3^t \times 5^s), ~(2^s \times 3^r \times 5^t), \\
~(2^s \times 3^t \times 5^r), ~(2^t \times 3^r \times 5^s), ~(2^t \times 3^s \times 5^r),$$
the smallest will be $~(2^r \times 3^s \times 5^t).$
As an illustrative example, comparing $~(2^r \times 3^s \times 5^t)~$ against
$~(2^r \times 3^t \times 5^s)~$ reduces to comparing
$~(3^s \times 5^t)~$ against
$~(3^t \times 5^s).~$
Remembering that $~r \geq s \geq t,~$ you have that
$$(3^s \times 5^t) = 3^{s - t} \times (3^t \times 5^t) \leq 5^{s - t} \times (3^t \times 5^t) = (3^t \times 5^s).$$

So, with $~d~$ so constrained, since $~5^3 > 99,~$ you can immediately conclude that $~t \in \{0,1,2\}.~$
Further, since $~r \geq s \geq t,~$ and 
since $~(2^2 \times 3^2 \times 5^2) > 99,~$ 
you can eliminate $~t = 2.~$
The remainder of this analysis is case-work.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~t = 1}$
Then $~d~$ must have form $~2^r \times 3^s \times 5^1,~$ where $~r,s \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$
Setting $~e = \dfrac{d}{5},~$ you have that

$e = 2^r \times 3^s ~: ~r \geq s \geq 1.$

$\displaystyle e \leq \left\lfloor \frac{99}{5}\right\rfloor = 19.$


Since $~2^2 \times 3^2 > 19,~$ you must have that $~s = 1.~$
Then, since $~(2^2 \times 3^1) \leq 19 < (2^3 \times 3^1),~$ you must have that $~e = 2^2 \times 3^1.~$
Therefore, the Case 1 candidate is
$$d = (2^2 \times 3^1 \times 5^1)$$
which will have $~(2 + 1) \times (1 + 1) \times (1 + 1) = 12~$ factors.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~t = 0}$
Then, $~d~$ must have form $~2^r \times 3^s ~: ~r \geq s \geq 0,~$ 
where $~10 \leq (2^r \times 3^s) \leq 99.$
Since $~(2^3 \times 3^3) > 99,~$ you must have that $~s \in \{0,1,2\}.~$
Note that for each value of $~s,~$ you will want to choose $~r \geq s~$ such that $~(2^r \times 3^s) \leq 99 < (2^{r+1} \times 3^s).$
So, the candidates are :

$d = 2^3 \times 3^2 ~: ~4 \times 3 = 12~$ factors.

$d = 2^5 \times 3^1 ~: ~6 \times 2 = 12~$ factors.

$d = 2^6 \times 3^0 ~: ~7 \times 1 = 7~$ factors.



Combining the results of Case 1 and Case 2, you see that there are $~3~$ distinct numbers that each have $~12~$ factors:
$$(2^2 \times 3^1 \times 5^1) = 60, ~~(2^3 \times 3^2) = 72, ~~(2^5 \times 3^1) = 96.$$
Therefore, the minimum number $~d~$ is $~60.$
Therefore, the minimum number $~c~$ is $~6060 = 60 \times 101.$

I like this solution.

One observation is that if the number has $k$ distinct prime factors, then these have to be the smallest $k$ primes, in decreasing order of multiplicity. E.g. if you know the number is of the form $p^4q$ then $p=2$ and $q=3$ since any other combination has the same number of factors, but is larger. Also, that example gives something less than $50$, which can't be right, since doubling it gives more factors.
This means the only plausible candidates are $2^6$, $2^5\times 3$, $2^3\times 3^2$, $2^2\times 3\times 5$. (The smallest number with a $7$ is $2\times3\times5\times 7$, too big, the smallest with $3^3$ is $2^33^3$, too big, and similarly for $3^2\times5$, so you just need to try multiplying $1$, $3$, $3^2$ and $3\times 5$ by the largest power of $2$ that fits.) The first one isn't right because it has less factors than the others, and $2^2\times 3\times 5$ is the smallest of the three with $12$ factors.

How did you got $2^6,2^5 * 3$ etc?

@Geometry99 There's only one plausible candidate of the form $p^a$, which is $2^a$ with $a$ as large as possible. Similarly the only option of the form $p^bq$ is $2^b\times 3$ with $b$ as large as possible, and so on. Once we get to something like $p^aq^2r$ with $a\geq 2$, the smallest such number is already too big (it is 180).
